# SQL Server table optimization please

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

I am trying to fetching data from a SQL Server table through PHP. Problem with execution time is too long. Can anybody please create an index for this table? My searching is based on `r_text` table. I just want to create an index for that column. Please alter the below table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tab_res](
        [r_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [r_path] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [r_name] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [r_time] [datetime] NULL,
        [r_time] [datetime] NULL,
        [r_text] [text] NULL,
        [r_res_text] [text] NULL,
        [r_newpath] [varchar](500) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Res] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [r_id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
```

Comment: Show your query too, as well as any other indexes on the table. We can't tell you what is causing your query to be slow when we only know the table structure.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830241/ms-sql-server-index-on-text-column): "Searching TEXT fields is always pretty slow. Give [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) a try and see if that works better for you."